# how to create a new numpy array by masking another numpy array with a single assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking

Supposing A is an NP array.

If I do this:

```
B = np.copy(A)
B[B !=0] = 1
```

or

```
A[A != 0]=1
B=np.copy(A)
```

I get B as the masked version of A, i.e. the desired output. However if I try the assignment like this:

```
B= A[A !=0]=1
```

B becomes an integer for reasons I don't understand.  Why does this happen and is there a way or performance reason to perform this operation as a single assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must preface this by saying any attempt in doing so massively decreases readability. Just use two lines if you don't want to other people (or yourself) to ever work with that code again. This answer is just supposed to demonstrate what *could* be done, not what *should* be done.

The expression `A=B=x` assigns `x` to both `A` and `B`. If you really want to squeeze everything onto one line you could try something like

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5)
(b:=a.copy())[a!=0]=1
```

The `:=` (walrus) operator actually evaluates to the assigned value, unlike the assignment (`=`) operator. (Note that `A=B=x` works because it is basically a shorthand for `t=x; A=t; B=t`, but `A=(B=x)` will not work as the assignment does not evaluate to anything. You chould write `A=(B:=x)` though.) Then `a` remains unchanged, which corresponds to your first version, so

```
>>> b
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: great thanks this is very helpful!! Sorry I'm having trouble understanding the syntax of the walrus. So b is assigned the value a.copy() with the mask [a!=0]=1 so why are there parenthesis around the b:= a.copy()? (I know i get a syntax error without but just trying to get a better understanding of how the operator is working thanks!

Comment: also is there a reason this operator wouldn't work on a view of an np.array?  for example if i try (b:=a.copy())[::-1], it will first show me a reversed view of a but each time I call b it will return the original version of a.

Comment: @flawr: Do you know of any documentation that gives the official semantics of A=B=expr?  I spent about twenty minutes looking and couldn't find anything.  Hence my answer.

Comment: @phntm `X:=Y` evaluates to the right hand side of the `:=` operand, and assigns the value of the rhs to the target on the lhs (`X`). So in my example we first evaluate `a.copy()` (an array), then assign it to `b`, and then index this array to inject some zeroes. So only the array that was returned from `a.copy()` and assigned to `b` gets modified. In your example `(b:=a.copy())[::-1]` we first assign again `a.copy()` to `b` and then index it. But just indexing does not modify it! If you want the behaviour you expected you'd need to write `b:=(a.copy()[::-1])` I recommend looking up the docs!

Comment: @FrankYellin check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements). In the definition of `assignment_stmt` you can see that you can have an arbitrary positive number of `target_list` (separated by `=`) in there.

Comment: @flawr.  I missed the plus sign after (target_list '=').  And yes, now that I see that, it is quite explicit.  I didn't realize that A = B = 1 explicitly assigns to A before it assigns to B; that's the opposite of some other languages I've dealt with in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're seeing that `B` has the value 1?

In all computer languages, there is some ambiguity as to what `X = Y = expr` means.  Does it mean to assign expr to Y, and then to assign Y to X?  Or does it mean to assign expr to both X and Y.  Numpy clearly believes it means the latter.

You will see the same behavior with

```
b = np.zeros((5))
a = b[0] = 1
```

You will see that a is assigned 1, even though `b[0] == 1.0`

Comment: Note.  I've been looking through the Python documentation trying to find an official statement as to the meaning of `A = B = expression` in python.  (Are we assigning expression to A, or B to A?). I've not yet managed to find anything.

Comment: “In all computer languages, there is some ambiguity...” This is BS. In C and C++ this is very well defined. Apparently in Python it is too (see other answer). And I can’t imagine an expression like that being legal but ambiguous in any sane language. Either it is well defined, or it is illegal.

Comment: @CrisLuengo.  Meanwhile, here is a quora article saying that in C++ "it depends."  So don't tell me it's BS.  And there are lots of languages other than C and C++.  

https://www.quora.com/C++-does-a-b-1-assign-a-value-of-b-or-1-to-a

Comment: How it is evaluated and what it evaluates to is clearly defined in the C++ specs. Someone on Quora doesn't know this, awesome. Doesn't mean it's not well defined. // If you said "in some languages..." or something like that, it'd be OK. But you can't say "in all languages...", just because you don't know all languages and don't know if there's a language out there where your statement doesn't hold.

Comment: @CrisLuengo.  I half agree with you.  The guidelines says what implementors of libraries are *expected* to do.  But there are libraries that don't follow the guidelines.  In Python, it is clearly defined that expr is independently assigned to A and B.  In C++, the specification is that A = B = expr is A = (B = expr), and it relies on library writers to return the correct value when overriding =.  Sorry, that's convention, not "well defined".   Python is well defined.

Comment: @CrisLuengo:  You are right that "not all languages have this ambiguity."  Perhaps I should have written that "different languages assign different semantics to A = B = expr.  Without reading the specification, it is hard to know in advance how any specific language deals with the issue."   Better?

Comment: That would certainly be better! Regarding C++, it's not the *library* but the *compiler* that implements this behavior. And if the compiler implements it differently than the standard specifies, then it's not a standards-compliant compiler, and that would be quite troubling. Note that the standard is [an actual ISO standard](https://www.iso.org/standard/68564.html), not a mere convention.